# Replace smartcodes with gsub

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I work on ruby > 3.0 and i need to replace a text content (in-line html text with smartcode).
this text can be long and for example it's like this : "Hello, {{viewer_name}} ! How are you ?"

I have a method to replace theses smartcodes :

```rb
def populate_smartcodes(content)
  content.gsub(/\{{(.*?)\}}/).each do |value|
    smartcode = value[/#{Regexp.escape('{{')}(.*?)#{Regexp.escape('}}')}/m, 1]
    str_smartcode = "{{#{smartcode}}}"
    case smartcode
    when 'viewer_name'
      content = content.gsub(str_smartcode, viewer.name)
    when 'company_city'
      content = content.gsub(str_smartcode, company.city )
    end
    content
  end
```

`company_city` and `viewer_name` are variables i need to provide with viewer an instance of User::Viewer.

And i have a lot of smartcodes to replace ... I think this is not a good way to do it but it's working.

Can you help me to improve the performance or the way to do it ?

Edit :

I have pdf content shown to the user, they just have a list of 'keys' or 'smartcode' available, this way everyone can change their pdf as the want to (through the content). We keep only a text with the pdf content in the database. Maybe we can use another strategy ?
For now i wanted a way to replace string element by another value.

Comment: What is a _"smartcode"_?

Comment: @Stefan it's juste an anchor (if i could say) to pinpoint the location of the part of the string i want to replace with some values. for ex: " I need to do {{this}} "  in this example my smartcode is '{{this}}' and i want to change it by 'dishes'. the result will be "I need to do dishes". and I can't do string interpolation because i parse a pdf...

Comment: Why not use [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) or [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/)?

Comment: *"I can't do string interpolation because i parse a pdf"* -- Could you elaborate on this? Nothing in your question indicates string interpolation wouldn't solve the problem in a simple and elegant way.

Comment: @TomLord you're right, i didn't specify this on the question. I have pdf content shown to the user, they just have a list of 'keys' or 'smartcode' available, this way everyone can change their pdf as the want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're running a new gsub inside an existing gsub block, which isn't necessary, since the gsub block will substitute each match with the return value of the block anyway. The same result could be achieved simply with 2 lines of code:

```
content.gsub!(/{{viewer_name}}/, viewer.name)
content.gsub!(/{{company_city}}/, company.city)
```

...but that is still analyzing the whole string twice. If you know all of the smartcodes beforehand, you could do something like this instead:

```
def populate_smartcodes(content)
  content.gsub(/{{\w*}}/) do |smartcode|
    case smartcode
    when '{{viewer_name}}'
      viewer.name
    when '{{company_city}}'
      company.city
    else
      smartcode
    end
  end
end
```

This will return a copy of the input string with all instances of `{{viewer_name}}` and `{{company_city}}` replaced. You could also use `gsub!` instead of `gsub` if you want to modify the original string in place, so you can call it like `populate_smartcodes(original_string)` instead of `original_string = populate_smartcodes(original_string)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extract smartcodes from the template in a much simpler (cleaner?) way. We know for sure, that they always contain 4 parentheses - 2 from each side. So we can just take what `gsub` matches, and take `2..-3` chars as the actual binding name:

```rb
content = "Hello, {{viewer_name}}! How are you?"

content.gsub!(/{{\w+?)}}/) do |matched_chunk|
  matched_chunk[2..-3] # => viewer_name
end
```

Next, we would like to resolve these matched smartcodes into something meaningful. *And we would like to do it dynamically to avoid hardcoding of many-many individual smartcodes, correct*?

In your example you resolve `viewer_name` into `viewer.name` and `company_city` into `company.city` - it looks like some pattern `<receiver>.<property>`. If this is the case, we could use this "generality" to resolve things dynamically without the need to hardcode resolution for each "smartcode":

```rb
content.gsub!(/{{\w+?)}}/) do |matched_chunk|
  recv, prop = matched_chunk[2..-3].split("_", 2)
  instance_eval("#{recv}.#{prop}") # the receiver should be defined in the current scope, obviously
rescue
  matched_chunk
end
```

Well, it could work. Probably :) But it smells as hell:

- I limit the split by 2, to ensure we always stick with `receiver.property` pattern. So, something like `user_first_name` will be resolved as `user.first_name`. But this assumption might be just wrong in general! It might be in fact something like `user.first.name`, or even `foo_bar` that should be resolved into `something_else` - so this solution is fragile *at minimum*...
- `instance_eval` is a Pandora box, and we should be extremely careful with it. Idealy, We should call it in an isolated, safe context (some blank slate object)

Both of these problems are solvable: we can create a special template builder object as a safe blank late context for our `instance_eval`; we could then inject the necessary bindings so that instance_eval could resolve our smartcodes properly (in this case we could even replace instance_eval with safer magic or maybe no magic at all - hardcoding things sometimes is not *that* bad idea) etc...

But following this rabbit hole, we would sooner or later recreate something like `liquid` or `mustache`, just way less mature and more error-prone.

So my proposal is don't play around regexes, try to adopt some battle-tested template engine first (and roll back to the custom implementation only if you have really strong reasons) :)

Comment: yeah sorry. i should have precised  that viewer_name replaced by viewer.name is just for the example. to be easier to understand. But some smartcodes are more complicated. I'm on the process to clean this method ..